# I deleted windows8 and installed ubuntu 14.04 but now I cant boot

Tags: 14.04, windows

Boot repair discovered this for me http://paste.ubuntu.com/7766025/
Every time I try to boot there is no boot device detected

Comment: Do you have secure boot disabled?

Comment: You may want to read this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/178596

Comment: I have deleted the preinstalled windows maybee that was rash but I couldnt figure out how to install ubuntu otherwise... now all I get when I try to boot is reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key

Comment: Im booting with a ubuntu live disk, I have used boot repair but the fixes didnt solve anything